# R - create a sequence of odd numbers followed by the sequence of even numbers on the same interval

Tags: r, vector, sequence

So I am basically looking for a more efficient way to do this:

```
c(seq(1, 5, 2), seq(2, 6, 2))
```

Is there a simpler function built in R or some of the packages that would allow me to specify just one interval (from 1 to 6; instead of having to specify from 1 to 5 and from 2 to 6), but to sort the numbers so that all the odd numbers appear before the even ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sequence`. The first argument of the function is the length of each sequence, `from` is the starting point, and `by` is the interval.

```r
sequence(c(3, 3), from = c(1, 2), by = 2)
#[1] 1 3 5 2 4 6
```

---

Or, as a function that fits your request:

```r
seqOrdered <- function(from = 1, to){
  n = ceiling((to - from) / 2)
  sequence(c(n, n), from = c(from, from + 1), by = 2)
}

seqOrdered(1, 6)
#[1] 1 3 5 2 4 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Just concatenate the sub-data that contains only odd numbers of the original data and the other sub-data that contains the remaining even numbers.

In the following, you can have the original data `x1`, which consists of 10 integers from a poisson distribution of mean 8 (`rpois(n = 10, lambda = 8)`), and merge the sub-data of odd numbers (`x1[x1 %% 2 == 1]`) and that of even numbers (`x1[x1 %% 2 == 0]`).

```r
## To prepare data
x1 <- rpois(n = 10, lambda = 8)
x1

## To sort the data so that odd numbers come earlier
c(x1[x1 %% 2 == 1], x1[x1 %% 2 == 0])
```